# Python - When accumulating info over multiple calls - to use globals or not

Tags: python, global-variables

Though there are many threads on why not to use global variables, usually illustrated by examples, I haven't found a direct answer to this one. So, here's my own ver of the "why globals are bad?" question:

Following a piece of code (dumb but representative):

```
Vegetables = ['avocado', 'asparagus', 'broccoli', ..., 'tomato']
TheVegetablesSurvey = dict.fromkeys(Vegetables, 0)

def vote_for_vegetables():
  veg = raw_input("What's your favorite veg?").lower()
  if veg in TheVegetablesSurvey: 
    TheVegetablesSurvey[veg] += 1
    print 'Thank you!'
  else:
    print "Sorry, we don't know this vegetable, try again..."

def show_survey():
  print "The results are:"
  for veg in sort_by_value(TheVegetablesSurvey) # supposed to exist, irrelevant
    print "%-20s, %d"%(veg, TheVegetablesSurvey[veg])
```

Now, since globals are bad, what would be the better alternative for **TheVegetablesSurvey**?

Thanks!

P.S. - If I've missed an obviously similar thread, than please...

Comment: Pass `TheVegetablesSurvey` as an argument to your functions. Also, read [PEP-0008](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are not necessarily bad, and you if you handle the scope thing of python, you can use globals in a good way.
Mainly, python preferes in your case to pass your dict as a function argument because it is more explicit that this function need a dict that will be increment.

Here you could just do : `def vote_for_vegetables(somedict)`.

In some case, if you have five or six function using the same arguments, you can keep it global to keep the code less verbose, but guessing this functions won't be needed in many other files, because you'll need to set as many global as you have to use these.

Comment: In that case, `somedict` should be a WS-level variable to aggregate and display the results. I'm not sure this is better (and often not-applicable)

Comment: or you just return it and re catch it calling function like : `Thevegetablessurvey = vote_for_vegetables(Thevegetablessurvey)`